# How to use an ajax call's response to manipulate a dynamic page?

Tags: ajax

I am trying to submit a form with the user's inserted data and get the html back from the page called (update.asp).

1. How do I get the html response and how do I write it to a div on the page? The response would be "success".
2. If my page throws a 500 or other type of error, how can I handle that?

   ```
   $('input#btnUpdate').click( function() {
       $.ajax({
       url: 'update.asp',
       type: 'post',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
       success: function(data) {
           // how do i catch the response? is this the right place?
       },
       error: function(data) {
           // how do I catch the error code here?
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The response from the server in both cases would be passed to the callback as the data variable in your example. Try using console.log(data) inside of your callbacks to see the result in your developer console.

Comment: good call. I did that but it only works if i put it in the error: option. the statuscode is 200 and I see the responseText "success" which is what I write out at the end of the page.   any idea why it does not work when I do console.log in the success: option?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input#btnUpdate').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.asp',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
              $("#yourDIV").html(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)  {
              alert(thrownError);        //output, 500
        }
    });
});
```

More on this: [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Sean, this code works! I am getting error:Syntax Error Unexpected Token s

Comment: Can you send the webpage's link? @DMoney